# How to send CORS redirect with three different origins?

Tags: javascript, redirect, browser, cors, w3c

I have an app in `a.com`, which requests a resource in `b.com`.
In some cases, `b.com` will redirect the client to `c.com`.

After such redirect the browser will set `Origin: null` header (this complies with the spec)

I don't want to allow `Origin: null` in `c.com` as this will expose a security vulnerability.

Is there any workaround for such case?
I could send the redirect in the response text, but I'd prefer a more standardized way to resolve this issue.

In case it wasn't clear, here's the full flow:

1. `a.com` -> `b.com` (`Origin: a.com`)
2. `b.com` sends `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: a.com` and a 302 redirect to `c.com`
3. browser sends request to `c.com` with `Origin: null`, but `c.com` can't
       know that the resource came from `a.com` which he trusts, and therefore we get a CORS failure.

Comment: Redirect to a.com with instructions to get data from c.com?